# CSS link colour different display to css code?

Tags: css

I'm doing a design for CSS Zen Garden, partly to refresh my CSS skill and knowledge and have found a problem with link colours in my css code.

[image: CSS link colours different with same css code]

As shown in my annotated image, the a:link color (#b7a5df) seems to create x2 link colours!
eg some links are #b7a5df colour but others for some reason are #d7cddc!

The css code is the standard in the CSSZenGarden default.css file eg:

```
    a:link { 
font-weight: bold; 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #B7A5DF;
}
    a:visited { 
font-weight: bold; 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #D4CDDC;
}
    a:hover, a:focus, a:active { 
text-decoration: underline; 
color: #9685BA;
}
```

At the moment I cannot see why this should be and am grateful for  any ideas of what might be causing this so I can find and fix the link color to be the same!
It is most likely to be caused by something simple I've overlooked but it is frustrating
and I'd appreciate a second opinion now-thanks!

EDIT...The above problem is with FireFox. The links display the same colour in IE and Chrome. Below is an image from IE:
[image]

Comment: Use (Right-click ->) Inspect Element in Google Chrome (works similarly in Firefox) on your link to inspect the element's CSS. It should show you which CSS lines affect your link and where these lines are declared.

Comment: Well obviously you have defined the #d7cddc color somewhere else in your code. Please share that code too.

Comment: Hi Guys..the bizarre thing is when I inspect the css for the link colour #d7cddc, the css rule is a:link {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #B7A5DF;
}

Comment: Without a demo we can't really find a solution.  Are you able to put  one on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I've just tried the code in IE and the links are all the same colour as expected! I have been looking at this in Firefox and I guess then it is some bad browser behaviour?

Comment: Try clicking refresh button while holding shift key ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are the visited links.

"a:visited" is the colour of links to pages you have previously been on.

"a:link" is the colour of unvisited links

You could also just use "a" alone if you want to colour all types of link.

How did you get the D7CDDC value?  It is so close to D4CDDC, that I suspect it is actually the D4CDDC a:visited colour.